# Compiling Titanium Modules from GitHub

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, titanium-modules

After a few days of failure I realize I need more insight than google can deliver.

I am attempting to include a module in my otherwise working fine Titanium project but am not having any luck.  The module in question is [Ti.MapPlus](https://github.com/AppWerft/Ti.MapPlus), a fork of the standard Ti.Map module that I am already using. The GitHub repository does not have a compiled release, and it is not available via Gitt.io.

I have tried to create a new Mobile Module Project without success; but suspect that this is the best route.

Can anybody walk me through the steps of getting the module working globally?

Comment: You could join http://tislack.org/ and ask @appwerft there. He is very active there and might help with it.

Answer (score 1):

There are some releases here: https://github.com/AppWerft/Ti.MapPlus/releases

Comment: I tried the 2.8.2 release, but when building the app I received an error:

[ERROR] :  Module ti.map version 2.8.2 is missing library file: / Library/Application Support/Titanium/modules/iphone/ti.map/2.8.2/libti.map.a